# How to add number of NA's to a bar plot where NAs are not included

Tags: r, ggplot2, na, geom-bar

I am trying to add data about the number of NAs observed in a bar chart, as simple text -- see example below.

I keep banging my head on either filtering out all NAs prior to the ggplot call -- which forces me to rely on annotate("text" ...) to add an extra layer (dissociated from the original plot data) -- or keeping the NAs in the plot data, filtering them out in the geom_bar call and adding a geom_text ... I'm not having much luck though.

The code for a minimal working example:

```
df <- data.frame(y = factor(sample(letters[24:26], 50, replace=TRUE)), x = factor(sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA), 50, replace=TRUE)))
df[df$y=="x" & is.na(df$x),'x'] <- "A"
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, fill=x)) + geom_bar(position="fill")
```

...line 2 in the code is simply to ensure that one of the grouping variable instances (y) has no NAs.

The output:

[image: Plot created with MWE code]

The desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you calculate the total of na per group to a new column and use that to display that on top of the bars like this:

```r
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(y = factor(sample(letters[24:26], 50, replace=TRUE)), x = factor(sample(c(LETTERS[1:3], NA), 50, replace=TRUE)))
df[df$y=="x" & is.na(df$x),'x'] <- "A"

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(total_na = sum(is.na(x))) %>%
  drop_na(x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=y, fill=x)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, label = paste0("NA: ", total_na)), hjust = 0, size = 3) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That would work too -- a solution with some data redundancy, but hey! ... it if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit you?

0.This option gives you the required text labels as well.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=y, fill=x), position="fill", data = function(d) filter(d, !is.na(x)))+
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = y, label = n), data = function(d) d %>% 
              filter(is.na(x)) %>% 
              group_by(y) %>% 
              count %>% 
              transmute(n = paste0("NA: ", n)), hjust = 1)
```

[image]

or like this if you need zeroes plotted:

```
  ggplot(df) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y=y, fill=x), position="fill", data = function(d) filter(d, !is.na(x)))+
    geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = y, label = n), data = function(d) d %>% 
                filter(is.na(x)) %>% 
                count(y, .drop = F) %>%  
                transmute(y, n = paste0("NA: ", n)), hjust = 1)
```

[image]

1.Filtering inside geom_*:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, fill=x)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", data = function(d) filter(d, !is.na(x)))
```

[image]

2.Filtering before passing data to `ggplot()`:

```
filter(df, !is.na(x)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(y=y, fill=x)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill")
```

3.Filtering without dplyr `filter()` and `%>%` calls:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=y, fill=x)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", data = function(d) d[!is.na(d$x),])
```

or

```
df[!is.na(df$x),] |>
ggplot(aes(y=y, fill=x)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill")
```

Comment: I think it might ... I'll try it out and see if I can wrangle the text in there as well

Comment: @SørenONeill Kindly see the second option - filtering the dataset prior passing it to `ggplot()` call

Comment: the problem with filtering before passing to ggplot2 is the NA data is lost, and therefor not able to present within the plot itself ... hence the possibility of using annotate, but I'd like to avoid that

Comment: @SørenONeill And what about the 0th option just appended?

Comment: That solution works!